# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyEnvironment.getResourceConfig()Lcom/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig;

Tags: java, jersey, integration-testing, dropwizard

I'm trying to access a legacy module and write Integration tests using zero code framework. In integration test module, I'm using dropwizard - 1.13.2 version and the original module is in 0.7.1 version. When using [DropwizardAppRule](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=io.dropwizard.testing.junit.DropwizardAppRule), I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyEnvironment.getResourceConfig()Lcom/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig;

    at com.xyz.hubsystem.bootstrap.ResourceConfig.bindResources(ResourceConfig.java:108)
    at com.xyz.hubsystem.HubSystemApplication.run(HubSystemApplication.java:114)
    at com.xyz.hubsystem.HubSystemApplication.run(HubSystemApplication.java:57)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.DropwizardTestSupport.startIfRequired(DropwizardTestSupport.java:237)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.DropwizardTestSupport.before(DropwizardTestSupport.java:151)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.junit.DropwizardAppRule.before(DropwizardAppRule.java:159)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Here is the answer: https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice/issues/37

Comment: Dropwizard migrated to `Jersey 2` in version `0.8`. You'll have to upgrade the code of the module or downgrade the version of `dropwizard` you are using.

Comment: The stacktrace is remarkably similar: https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guice/issues/37#issuecomment-62813499